# How to use callback url in twilio codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio

```
     $data = array(
                        'From' => $from, 
                        'To' => $to, 
                        'Url' => site_url('dashboard/call2')
            );
     // make call request to Twilio

     try{ 
          $twilio = new TwilioRestClient($account_sid, $account_token);
          $result = $twilio->request('2010-04-01/Accounts/'. $account_sid .'/Calls', 
                    'POST', 
                    $data
                    );
            pr($result);
         }
         catch (Exception $e){
                pr($e);
         }


     public function call2() {
         $this->load->view('response');
     }
```

here response is a xml file in views. response.xml has to call as callback url.
but it is showing error:

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://www.website.com/index.php/dashboard/call2
Line Number 1, Column 5:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is leading whitespace before the `<?xml` declaration. This will cause the document to fail to be parsed.

Check if there is whitespace outside of your PHP tags, including possibly after a closing `?>` tag. This will show up in the XML output.

Comment: yeah , u answered right there was a space before xml tags . but you responded late and now it is fixed. Thanks